# Why can't I run an exe with a specific filename?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, windows-7, dependencies

I have recently encountered a problem on my Windows 7 machine where I can't run an application with a specific name. Let's call it a.exe.

It is a C++ Qt based app and has been working OK for months but when I tried to run it today I got "The application was unable to start correctly (0x80000003). Click OK to close the application.". This happens for both 32-bit and 64-bit builds for Debug or Release.

I spent hours going round in circles checking dependencies and rolling back to previous versions without getting anywhere. I tried the software on a different machine and it worked, so it must be something on my machine...

I finally discovered that if I rename it to something else (e.g. a1.exe) then it will work :-S

I've checked the VirtualStore folder but couldn't see anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: Any chance there is ANOTHER file with the same name, somewhere in your path?

Comment: gflags maybe? Look under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options" (check under wow6432node too) for the name of the file.

Comment: @avakar There was an entry under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options" and when I removed it, I could run the program. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: Could your virus checker be involved?

Comment: Are you specifying file extension even when your (Folder options --> View --> Hide extensions for file types) is enabled? If so uncheck & try again

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions but I have already solved it thanks to @avakar. See my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your "known file extensions" are hided, and you are trying to access a.exe when actually the file name is a.exe.exe?